# amcharts issue to fill bar of column chart with synchronized axis

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I have the following jsfiddle example: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wnvjx1x/)
Using the following js:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true
  },
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "id": "v1",
    "axisColor": "#FF6600",
    "axisThickness": 5,
    "gridAlpha": 0.1,
    "axisAlpha": 1
  }, {
    "id": "v2",
    "axisColor": "#FCD202",
    "axisThickness": 5,
    "gridAlpha": 0,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "synchronizeWith": "v1",
    "synchronizationMultiplier": 5
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    "type": "column",
     "fillColors": "#008800",
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, 
 ...
```

I expect the parameter  "fillColors": "#008800", to change the columns of the chart to green with green fill, but I do not reach this result. They stay with this red outline only.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `"fillAlphas"`. for example i set it to 1. [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqhnuf1g/)

```
  "graphs": [{
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    "type": "column",
     "fillColors": "#008800",
     "fillAlphas":1, /* here i set it */
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "visits"
  }, {
    "valueAxis": "v2",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "lineColor": "#c2c2c2",

    "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "yellow line",
    "valueField": "hits",
    "fillAlphas": 0
  }],
```